# Make floated divs create scrollbars within another div?

Tags: html, scroll

I have multiple divs floated to the left within another div. Now when those divs are wider together than the div they are in they go to the next line, instead of making a horizontal scrollbar like I wanted it!
My CSS for my divs:

outer div:

```
display:block;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:black;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:20px;
width:200px;
overflow:auto;
```

inner divs:

```
min-width:16px; //contains text, so it gets wider usually
float:left;
padding-left:2px;
padding-right:2px;
```

Comment: Have you tried using `overflow-x: scroll` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add overflow-x: scroll to the outerdiv. FYI: The overflow-x property does not work properly in IE8 and earlier. So if you need it to work in IE8 or earlier, you'll likely need a javascript solution.

Comment: Tried that, it created a scrollbar, but my divs still went to the next line instead of staying on the line they were on.

Comment: You could make another div inside of 'outer' div that wraps the smaller div, and use javascript to calculate the total width of the inner divs, then set that width on the new div.